# Generating File with Ajax Fileupload

Tags: ajax, jquery-file-upload

My app is an MVC .NET 4.0 application.

My application is fairly straightforward. I open an text file and uploaded it to be processed and returned as an excel file. This works as expected.

The excel file is returned via an actionresult controller. There are no errors. It works the way I want it to.

The problem is that when I call ajaxStart with blockUI it works. However, upon returning the file, the ajaxStop or ajaxSuccess is never fired to turn off the spinner after the file result is displayed with a message - do you want to open the file or save it or cancel.

I'm using jquery fileupload, blockUI and jquery 1.9.1.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: fileuploadpath,
    autoUpload: true,
    beforeSend: function () {
    $.blockUI({ 
        timeout: 0,
        message: '<h1><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Processing...</h1>'
    }); 
    },
    complete: function() {
        //$.unblockUI();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {

        //$('.file_name').html(data.result.message.Name);
        //$('.file_type').html(data.result.message.Type);
        //$('.file_size').html(data.result.message.Length);
        $('.file_msg').html(data.result.message.Error);

    },
    success: function (data) {

        $.unblockUI();

        $('.file_msg').html(data.result.message.Error);
    }

});
```

and here is the basics of the file return in the action controller:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
return File(fileoutput, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Everything works just great. The area I'm scratching over my head is - why isn't the spinner being turned off after the file return? Am I missing something? I've tried binding ajaxStop and ajaxStart to the document but that does not work. ajaxStart gets fired but upon the file return, ajaxStop is being ignored.

Comment: There is any reason why you have commented out this line: $.unblockUI();. Additionally your ajax is a little confusing to me. From where have you got it?

Comment: : success was simply not getting called after the file came back...

Comment: I have already pointed you to this in the answer. The 'done' event makes the 'success' event not be fired. That's the reason I sad remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'done' and 'complete' event and use this format for your ajax call:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: fileuploadpath,
                    autoUpload: true,
                    timeout:60000,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#loader').show()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#loader').hide()
                         //$('.file_name').html(data.result.message.Name);
                        //$('.file_type').html(data.result.message.Type);
                        //$('.file_size').html(data.result.message.Length);
                        $('.file_msg').html(data.result.message.Error); //??? you are passing the error here
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#loader').hide()                       
                       if(textStatus==="timeout") {  
                           alert("A timeout occurred"); 
                       } else {
                           alert("This is  an other error"); 
                       }
                   }

                });
        });
```

**NOTE:** seen you have trouble with the blockUi, I have here used a other approach.

**TIMEOUT:**

I have set an extra parameter 'timeout' and set this to 60 sec. You coul set this to '0' which will be unlimited but it will be better practice to give it a limited value.

Place this in your HTML and give it a style of 'display:none' and an id.

```
<h1><img id="loader" src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none"/> Processing...</h1>'
```

Comment: Hi Franco - there was an error because the .done and .fail property did not work - I came up with this:
    }).ajaxComplete(function (data) {
        //your returned data by success here
        $.unblockUI();
    }).ajaxError(function (data) {
        //your returned data by error here
    });

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of jQuery, in this case remove the 'complete' and 'done' from your code, those are causing the problem, and use only  'success:' and 'error:'

Comment: As I pointed in my answer the problem is that you are using the 'done' event before the 'success' events. You only have to use the success event. The code in my example had a small typo that I have also corrected. But your code will work fine if you correct the issue with 'done'

Comment: Thanks - got it - but the file return still shows up and the spinner is left still spinning..the success does not seem to get called. I even added an alert message. The spinner should vanish when the file comes back...odd.

Comment: The unblockUi needs to know which element has to unblock. Anyway you could for this use also the 'show()' and hide() method, which is the one I always use and prefer.

Comment: That's correct on show and hide but success is not being called in this case and that's where I would want to use .hide(); which is problematic for me. The file uploads..but the process to generate the file may take 45 seconds or longer then it comes back but success is not called.

Comment: Wow. You didn't say that. If it takes so long to upload the file this will be a problem. Most browsers have default timeouts so when this is the case the file will be uploaded but you will automatically go to the error callback. Try to set the hide() event also in the error callback.

Comment: I have also changed the answer to try to handle that.

Comment: Just tried it. No go...it still spins when the file is ready to save...I'll play with this some more in the morning. Thanks much for your time...